# Golang: pass boolean flag from function in file/sub-directory A, to function in file/sub-directory B

Tags: go, architecture, boolean, flags

The following function lives in the folder [`go-ethereum/core/vm/instructions.go`](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/go-ethereum/blob/goethe_0.0/core/vm/instructions.go):

```
func opAdd(pc *uint64, evm *EVM, contract *Contract, memory *Memory, stack *Stack) ([]byte, error) {

    // begin execution time tracking
    var startTime = time.Now().UnixNano();

    x, y := stack.pop(), stack.pop()
    stack.push(math.U256(x.Add(x, y)))

    evm.interpreter.intPool.put(y)

    // log ellapsed execution time
    fmt.Println("execute opAdd consume = ",(time.Now().UnixNano() - startTime))

    return nil, nil
}
```

it's meant to output the execution time of the opcode `opAdd` in the execution of the Ethereum virtual machine, which looks like this:

[image]

However, what I'd like to do is have this information only display when it's running a programme that I've initiated locally, on my own network node.

Here is a function in the file [`go-ethereum/internal/ethapi/api.go`](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/go-ethereum/blob/master/internal/ethapi/api.go):

```
// SendRawTransaction will add the signed transaction to the transaction pool.
// The sender is responsible for signing the transaction and using the correct nonce.
func (s *PublicTransactionPoolAPI) SendRawTransaction(ctx context.Context, encodedTx hexutil.Bytes) (string, error) {
    tx := new(types.Transaction)
    if err := rlp.DecodeBytes(encodedTx, tx); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    if err := s.b.SendTx(ctx, tx); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    signer := types.MakeSigner(s.b.ChainConfig(), s.b.CurrentBlock().Number())
    if tx.To() == nil {
        from, err := types.Sender(signer, tx)
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        addr := crypto.CreateAddress(from, tx.Nonce())
        log.Info("Submitted contract creation", "fullhash", tx.Hash().Hex(), "contract", addr.Hex())
    } else {
        log.Info("Submitted transaction", "fullhash", tx.Hash().Hex(), "recipient", tx.To())
    }

    return tx.Hash().Hex(), nil
}
```

This function only executes when one submits a transaction to the network, and outputs `Submitted transaction` in the terminal window's console.

Is there a way that I could pass a boolean flag from `go-ethereum/internal/ethapi/api.go` to `go-ethereum/core/vm/instructions.go`, right before it outputs `Submitted transaction` so that I could execute the opcode execution time catalouging functionality?

---

**EDIT**

[image]

From the file `go-ethereum/internal/ethapi/api.go`:

```
// submitTransaction is a helper function that submits tx to txPool and logs a message.
func submitTransaction(ctx context.Context, b Backend, tx *types.Transaction) (common.Hash, error) {
    if err := b.SendTx(ctx, tx); err != nil {
        return common.Hash{}, err
    }
    if tx.To() == nil {
        signer := types.MakeSigner(b.ChainConfig(), b.CurrentBlock().Number())
        from, _ := types.Sender(signer, tx)
        addr := crypto.CreateAddress(from, tx.Nonce())
        log.Info("Submitted contract creation", "fullhash", tx.Hash().Hex(), "contract", addr.Hex())
    } else {

        // flag for opcode execution time tracking
        vm.OpcodeTrigger = true 

        log.Info("Submitted transaction", "fullhash", tx.Hash().Hex(), "recipient", tx.To())
    }
    return tx.Hash(), nil
}
```

and from `go-ethereum/core/vm/instructions.go`:

```
var (
    OpcodeTrigger bool
    bigZero = new(big.Int)
)

func opAdd(pc *uint64, evm *EVM, contract *Contract, memory *Memory, stack *Stack) ([]byte, error) {

    // wrap the logging in a check
    if OpcodeTrigger {
        // begin execution time tracking
        var startTime = time.Now().UnixNano();
    }

    x, y := stack.pop(), stack.pop()
    stack.push(math.U256(x.Add(x, y)))

    evm.interpreter.intPool.put(y)

    // wrap the logging in a check
    if OpcodeTrigger {
        // now set the boolean flag back to false
        OpcodeTrigger = false

        // log ellapsed execution time
        fmt.Println("execute opAdd consume = ",(time.Now().UnixNano() - startTime))
    }

    return nil, nil
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you want to do here? You want it to only output this debug information conditionally based on a flag you define?

Comment: kind of, I just want to be able to know if the file `go-ethereum/core/vm/instructions.go` when we enter the part of the loop that's going to output `"Submitted transaction"` from the function in `go-ethereum/internal/ethapi/api.go`, do you know how I could do that? like, maybe I could just mutually `include` the files, each one with the other, and create a global variable to declare when that loop is fired?

Comment: Do you want to time your code in api.go the way instructions.go does it, or do you want to control what instructions.go outputs when it is invoked (there's no clear linkage between the two here)? I think rather than ask about the boolean flag or linking files specify exactly what you want to happen in your bit of code.

Comment: so I want to boolean variable, that will record the execution time and output that only in the case that we enter that `"Submitted transaction"` loop, do you know what I mean?

Comment: Sorry, not clear. It'd be a lot clearer if you had working code to try. Do you want to control whether opAdd outputs or not depending on some condition? Does opAdd get called somewhere in the api.go file? I'd try to forget the how which you decided on and just specify the what very precisely.

Comment: aha, yes- sorry- you're right. so what I'd like to do is output those opcodes only in the situation where to code that's executing is the same code that would execute `"Submitted transaction"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To control whether timing information is output in instructions.go, yes you could add a boolean variable to the file instructions.go (perhaps something like):

```
var Debug bool
```

and wrap the logging in a check on it:

```
if Debug {
   // log ellapsed execution time
fmt.Println("execute opAdd consume = ",(time.Now().UnixNano() - startTime))
}
```

and then set it somewhere (for example in your api pkg) with

```
import ".../core/vm"
vm.Debug = true
```

this is not goroutine safe so would have to be set once on startup depending on conditions or protected with a mutex. It's also pretty horrible but as a quick hack to see it work you could do this (sorry not familiar with this particular code base) .

I'm not clear on how opAdd is triggered by your other code if it was directly called you could of course just add a parameter to the function to control the output from the calling site, this would be preferable.

Normally this sort of thing you'd either:

1. Pass in whether to debug or not to the function call opAdd
2. Set a global debugging level on startup once to control whether logging takes place or at what level globally and this would affect all such tracing.

They do have a log package, I don't know why it's not used here:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/log/logger.go

EDIT

I would just always allocate startTime , but if you wish to avoid that, you need to declare it at the top level, compare this to your code above:

```
// wrap the logging in a check
var startTime time.Time
if OpcodeTrigger {
    // begin execution time tracking
    startTime = time.Now().UnixNano();
}
```

NB if this is concurrent at all you should be adding a mutex to the vm pkg and only mutating OpCodeTrigger with a function which wraps the access with a mu.Lock - at that point you might start to ask yourself if there are better ways to do this :)

Better if you get stuck again to ask on a forum like forum.golangbridge.org as stackoverflow is not designed for extensive back and forth.

Comment: that's not what I want to do, I want the entering of the function that outputs `"Submitted transaction"` to trigger the timing of the opcodes in `instructions.go`

Comment: is this going to be accessible in `go-ethereum/core/vm/instructions.go` if I set it in `ethereum/internal/ethapi/api.go`?

Comment: so, currently it crashes- but- what do you think of the edit to the OP, does it look like it makes sense? what did I do wrong?

Comment: It could, though I think you have things inverted  - the lower level pkg should know nothing about the api one, it should have a flag, which it uses to control behaviour, which other packages can set. So instructions.go should contain and use the flag, and some other pkg sets it as appropriate. It's unusual for such a flag to be unset immediately after use as well. Hope this has helped a little, I'd try it out with real code.

Comment: so I changed it around, the lower level package thing and you suggested, but it still crashed, I put a screenshot of the error also into the OP as an edit

Comment: it says now that `core/vm/instructions.go:56: undefined: startTime`,  but it never crashed with that before, when I didn't have `startTime` wrapped in that way

Comment: Given the code above, you've wrapped starttime declaration, so it doesn't exist outside that scope. I've given an example above.

Comment: I finally got it to work- I've described it here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23941/filter-to-restrict-output-of-opcode-data-only-to-contracts-functions-called-by-l

Comment: but in fact- that approach- is sort of a hack- and doesn't really do what I want :/